# Lightweight B-tree library for Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, persistence, b-tree, dbm

Can anyone recommend a lightweight, fast, and hopefully stable B-tree (or similar) library for Java?

Essentially I'm looking for an on-disk map; something along the lines of BerkeleyDB JE, except I don't need transactions, am fine with read-only concurrency, and need it to be about 1/10th the size (BSD or Apache license would be nice, too).

Needs to be pure-Java, so no Tokyo/Kyoto Cabinets.

Implementing relevant `Collections` interfaces would be a plus (alternatively, templated interfaces for primitive types would be nice too).

[JDBM](http://jdbm.sourceforge.net/) looks pretty good, but it seems to have been abandoned in 2005 (at 1.0, no less).

There's also [DiskBackedMap](http://code.google.com/p/disk-backed-map/), but they released an alpha a year ago, and nothing since.

Anything else out there? Or any experiences with the above-mentioned ones?

Things I'm **NOT** looking for:

- In-process relational DBs (so no H2, Derby, SQLite, etc)
- Distributed key-value stores (no Redis, Memcachedb, Cassandra, Voldemort, Dumbledore, or whatever)

Comment: For educational use, there is http://www.cs.unm.edu/~rlpm/499/ttft.html No disk backing though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a fork of JDBM that might be of interest to you.

See http://www.kotek.net/blog/jdbm_2.1_and_beyond

GitHub: https://github.com/jankotek/JDBM3

Also,

Email: jdbm@googlegroups.com

Web: http://groups.google.com/group/jdbm

RSS: http://groups.google.com/group/jdbm/feed/rss_v2_0_msgs.xml

**EDIT:**

JDBM4 was renamed to [MapDB](https://github.com/jankotek/MapDB)

Answer (score 2):

Modern projects worth mentioning:

- [LMDBJava](https://github.com/lmdbjava/lmdbjava) allows to use [LMDB](https://symas.com/offerings/lightning-memory-mapped-database/) from Java. LMDB is not exactly B-tree, but it's a tree-like structure, i. e. always sorted.
- If you don't the sorted property, [Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) is [the most efficient](http://jetbrains.github.io/xodus/#benchmarks) random-access unordered persisted off-heap key-value store for Java now

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jankotek/MapDB might do part of what you want. That library provides several persistent list, set and map implementations, including a b-tree map.

Comment: I missed the detail about jdbm4 being renamed to MapDB in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

A late contribution, I know.
I myself don't need the excitement of choosing a Java DBM library. I need one merely to minimize memory usage in certain cases. (For actual persistence I'd use JPA.) There currently are 4 different JDBM projects in various states.

Luckily the Apache directory server comes with a JDBM library and my exciting times seem to be gone forever! The library  can be used separately and it seems to be based on one of the four implementations. It's also on [MVNRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.server/apacheds-jdbm/2.0.0-M5).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>apacheds-jdbm</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M5</version>
</dependency>
```